# How to get all values of input field which is generated in *ngFor

Tags: html, angular, typescript, ngfor

I have a form in which I have to select one or multiple customers, a date picker and a button.
The customer select has a "+" sign on the right that displays a new customer select right below with another "+" so you can add as many as needed.

**Html:**

```
<div fxLayout="row span" fxFlex.gt-sm="50" class="pr-20">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let item of [].constructor(customerNumber); let i = index let isLast = last">
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="80">
            <mat-label>Customer</mat-label>

            <autocomplete-input-field formControlName="{{ 'customer' + i }}" required
                                      [options]="customers"
                                      [getOptionIdFunction]="getCustomerId" [getOptionLabelFunction]="getCustomerName"
            >
            </autocomplete-input-field>
            <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">account_circle</mat-icon>

          </mat-form-field>
          <button *ngIf="isLast" mat-icon-button style="margin-top: 10px" color="primary" (click)="addCustomer()">
            <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
          </button>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
```

**Typescript**

```
export class CustomerHistoryMetricsComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  @ViewChild('downloadLink', {static: true}) private downloadLink: ElementRef;

  private _unsubscribeAll: Subject<any>;
  downloadingExcel: boolean;
  date = new FormControl(moment());
  yearSelected: number;
  monthSelected: number;
  customers: Customer[];
  customerNumber = 1;
  form: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _fuseTranslationLoaderService: FuseTranslationLoaderService,
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private metricsService: MetricsService,
    private fileService: FileService,


) {
    this._fuseTranslationLoaderService.loadTranslations(english, catalan, spanish);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._unsubscribeAll = new Subject();
    this.downloadingExcel = false;

    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
      customer1: ['', Validators.required],
      startDate: ['', Validators.required],

    });

    this.customerService.getAllActiveAndAllowedByPermission(Permission.CONSULT_CUSTOMERS)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this._unsubscribeAll))
      .subscribe(customers => {
        this.customers = customers;
        // this.setCustomerIfItIsTheOnlyOne();
      });
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this._unsubscribeAll.next();
    this._unsubscribeAll.complete();
  }

  public getCustomerId(customer: Customer): number {
    return customer.id;
  }

  public getCustomerName(customer: Customer): string {
    return customer.name;
  }

  public addCustomer(): void {
    this.customerNumber = this.customerNumber + 1;
    const controlName = `customer${this.customerNumber}`;
    this.form.addControl(controlName, new FormControl(''));
  }
```

I am using angular FormBuilder but I don't know how can I retrieve the values that the selects (autocomplete-input field) have when they are generated by an ngFor loop, I've tried like 15 different solutions but at this point I think I shouldnt be using ngFor

Comment: Why don't you use a form array ?